# Необъяснимое поведение глобального объекта Object в Opera

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

Вот такой **был** у меня фрагмент кода с добавлением глобального метода gsa (**G**et/**S**et **A**ttribute):

```
Object.prototype.gsa = function (){ 
  if (arguments.length == 1)    return this.getAttribute(arguments[0]);
  this.setAttribute(arguments[0],arguments[1]);
}
```

Когда большой проект был закончен, я решил "прогнать" его по всем браузерам (*на локальном сервере*). Надо же, во всех приложениях код работает. Однако Опера **внезапно** показала неожиданные результаты. Да, приложение на js полностью рабочее, ни к чему не придраться, но если открыть консоль разработчика, то видно, как выбрасывается исключение:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
at Object.gsa (config.js:12)
at t (ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1)
at X.X (ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1)
at X.serialize (ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1)
at X.ajax (ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1)
at Object.req (ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1)
at Storage.В (ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1)
at new Storage (ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1)
at ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:1
at ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js:2
```

Интересует первый файл в списке - config.js - это и есть мой файл конфигурации из проекта и подключается в первую очередь. (Остальные файлы не мои - работают, наверное, в недрах Оперы).

Через 3 часа поиска загадочного  обращения неизвестного объекта к методу gsa я  полностью изолировал этот фрагмент от остального кода. Следовательно, никаких подключений js-файлов нет, объекты не создаются и нет обращений к методу gsa. Проще говоря, весь js-код стал представлять из себя только этот фрагмент.  Но Опера все равно продолжает выбрасывать исключение. 
Конечно, я огорчился и в первой строке функции прописал:

```
if (!this) return;
```

Код стал исправно работать. 
Вопросы: почему в браузере Опера возникает такая ошибка? Какой объект без своего контекста this тайным образом обращается к методу gsa? Почему другие браузеры не ведут себя подобным образом?

UPDATE. Все браузеры обновлены до последней версии.

Comment: Опера же вебкитовская или вы еще последнюю на престо поддерживаете? Если последняя престовская, то там есть такая штука как browser.js, может она шалит?)

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/42.0.2393.95

Comment: экстеншнов никаких нету?

Comment: Короче - это явно не браузерная штука, а либа у вас где-то подклчюается, а где - вы понять не можете. В других браузерах работает, ибо подключается асинхронно. Может запросом скрипт тянется? аяксом или даже jsonp

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму , все подключаемые библиотеки написаны собственноручно. Для проверки кода я **не подключал ничего**. Говорю же, запустил только этот кусок кода и все.Ошибка не исчезает. Только явная проверка if (!this) return; помогает....

Comment: то есть хотите сказать что это происходит на пустой html страничке на чистом браузере без расширений? Не верю. Ваш коллстек ведет вас на загадочный js файл: ldr_656_11438_wFkRME.js. Беглое гугление приводит нас на одно использование js с таким именем: http://online-sovetytut.ru/. Посмотрев код этой странички видим, что он явно не ручками туда дописан, может тулза какая для сборки постаралась, может со скрипта где тянется.

Comment: Добавлю, что файлик-то явно обфусцирован. Не просто сжат, а именно обфусцирован чтобы никто случайно не прочитал что там делается, методами которые для просто сжатия - не используются. Может у вас сервак заражен чем-то и к страничке такой инклуд дописывает.

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму, сделайте ваш комментарием ответом про расширения - я приму как правильный ответ! Я не пользуюсь оперой, поэтому и не знал, что в ней могут присутствовать расширения. Оказалось, туда какой-то add-on музыкальный проник. После его удаления  все стало на свои места. Спасибо!

Comment: ок, нз) Интересно зачем они код так обфусцируют)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате тщательного расследования в комментариях было выяснено, что дело - просто в стороннем браузерном расширении.